# cypress | failed to use new command i have added in my test

Tags: cypress

i have added this  to command file:

```
Cypress.Commands.add("applyandSaveButtonsAreDisabled ", () => {
  cy.get("[data-a-key=base-modal-button-Save]").should("be.disabled");
  cy.get("[data-a-key=base-modal-button-Apply]").should("be.disabled");
});
```

but when trying to use it in my test:

```
it("Test inital state of Login tab ", () => {
     cy.get('[type="checkbox"]').check();
    cy.applyandSaveButtonsAreDisabled();
```

it fails with this error :

> TypeError: cy.applyandSaveButtonsAreDisabled is not a function

what am i doing wrong here?
do i need to add some referens to comand file from my test file?

Comment: The names are different. `applyandSaveButtonsAreEnabled` `applyandSaveButtonsAreDisabled`

Comment: correct but it is not the problem here,i fixed it and still get this error .

Comment: An update to your question would help others get a clearer picture of your issue.

Answer (score 0):

There's a space at the end of the command name causing your issue.

```js
// will not work
Cypress.Commands.add("applyandSaveButtonsAreDisabled ", () => {

// use this
Cypress.Commands.add("applyandSaveButtonsAreDisabled", () => {
```